# Simplifying Product of Transpositions

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, graph-algorithm

I am looking to take a product of a large number of transpositions, and boil it down to a smaller number of products. I have the following code, and would like some input on efficient ways to boil these products down. Before I give the code, it is important to recognize the following:

Transpositions, a cyclic permutation of two elements, have the following properties:

1. The product of identical transpositions cancel. For example, (1,2)(1,2)(2,3) = (2,3).
2. Any product of the form (x,y)(y,z)(x,y) is equal to (y,z)(x,y)(y,z).
3. Any transpositions which share no elements commute. That is, (u,v)(x,y)=(x,y)(u,v).

The code I have is below. This is a procedure which gets an input of a list that contains a number of 2-tuples which represent transpositions. For example, valid input is [(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)]. I have a small explanation at the bottom of the given code.

```
count = 1
while count != 0:
    count = 0
    repeatCount = 0
    swappedCount = 0
    for i in range(len(route)-1):
        if len(route) > 1 and repeatCount == 0:
            if route[i] == route[i+1]:
                route.pop(i+1)
                route.pop(i)
                count += 1
                repeatCount += 1

    for i in range(len(route)-3):
        if len(route) > 3 and swappedCount == 0:
            if route[i] == route[i+2] and route[i+1] == route[i+3]:
                route.pop(i+3)
                route.pop(i+2)
                route.insert(i,route[i+1])
                route.pop(i+2)
                count += 1
                swappedCount += 1
```

The first for loop searches of instances of property (1) above, and the second for loop search for instances of property (2). The counters repeatCounter and swappedCounter are my gross attempt to avoid an IndexError.

P.S Any way to accomplish this completely, i.e. always be able to reduce any product to the absolute minimum, in a timely way would be greatly appreciated, as run time is a problem for the rest of the whole program.

Comment: First, if you use python 2, use xrange instead of range, second the "pop" and "insert" calls on your list are time consuming because all values above insertion/deletion points must be moved to keep the list contiguous. If there are a lot of swaps, it can cost at lot. If there are few or no swaps, this is better than creating another list to replace the old one.

Comment: Could be a lot less readable, but could be done with deques and buffering the 4 last items: deletions & insertions would cost virtually nothing (rotate() would be needed)